# OpenNLP Custom POS Tagger : How to make Dictionary override input tags

Tags: dictionary, nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger

I am using OpenNLP for creating my own POS Tagger as follows

```
public Trainer(String trainingData, String modelSavePath, String dictionary){

        try {
            dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(
                    new File(classLoader.getResource(trainingData).getFile()));

            lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
            ObjectStream<POSSample> sampleStream = new WordTagSampleStream(lineStream);

            POSTaggerFactory fac=new POSTaggerFactory();

        if(dictionary!=null && dictionary.length()>0)
        {
            fac.setDictionary(new Dictionary(new FileInputStream(classLoader.getResource(dictionary).getFile())));
        }
            model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), fac);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Failed to read or parse training data, training failed
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (lineStream != null) {
                try {
                    lineStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Not an issue, training already finished.
                    // The exception should be logged and investigated
                    // if part of a production system.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

OutputStream modelOut = null;
        try {
            modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(modelSavePath));
            //modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getClass().getResource(modelSavePath).toURI())));
            model.serialize(modelOut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Failed to save model
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelOut != null) {
                try {
                    modelOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Failed to correctly save model.
                    // Written model might be invalid.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

which works well and saves the newly created model as a bin file. I want the dictionary terms to overwrite the words in my input and i do not see this behavior.

So consider the input

```
Mary_NNP had_VBD a_DT little_JJ lamb_NN
```

Now i want the tag to be

```
lamb_LAMB
```

so  put this in the dictionary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>
<entry tags="LAMB">
<token>lamb</token>
</entry>
</dictionary>
```

But when i try out the newly trained tagger, i still see the tag as `NN` for `lamb`

However, if my training data is

```
Mary_NNP had_VBD a_DT little_JJ lamb_LAMB
```

then it works as expected. Also, if i do not have the word `lamb` in my training data at all, then the custom generated tagger uses the dictionary tag.

How can i make sure that the dictionary tag always overrides the training data tag? Do i have to modify the training in any way?